# velodyne transform_node error require extrapolation

Tags: ros, tf-broadcaster, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am runing three nodes trying to transform a velodyne point_cloud with a /tf.

`rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=32E _pcap:=file.pcap`  (publishing /velodyne_packets)

`rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster` (publishing /tf with parent "base_link" and children "velodyne")
The kernel of my tf_broadcaster publish an increment translation :

```
int i=1;
while(n.ok()){
        broadcaster.sendTransform(
          tf::StampedTransform(
            tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), tf::Vector3(10+i, 20, 20)),
            ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "velodyne")); 
        r.sleep();
         i=i+1;
}
```

And the third node is:

```
rosrun velodyne_pointcloud transform_node _frame_id:=/base_link  _calibration:=32db.yaml
```

(subscribing /velodyne_packets and /tf and publishing /velodyne_points)

I am getting this error:

> Lookup would require extrapolation
> into the past.  Requested time 00.. but
> the earliest data is at time 00.., when
> looking up transform from frame
> [velodyne] to frame [base_link]

I have seen other answers about changing time(0) to time.now() but it is inside the code of transform_node provided by ROS and I don't think I should change it, do I? . I think the error should be in my parametrization. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Updated:

The error is at the beginning but the node still works apparently. In addition in some executions the error does not appear.

I have tried changing the _frame_id from the transform_node from /base_link to /velodyne and I get the same tf.

When I use rviz I see the same pointcloud, I can not see the applied transformation (translation). I use Decay time > 1 and I should see pointcloud accumulated and each new frame should be translated respect the previous one and I can not see the change.

Rqt_graph shows that transform_node is subscribed to /tf but I can not see the transformed point cloud.

```
rosrun tf tf_echo base_link velodyne
    At time 1465466281.155
    - Translation: [1005.000, 20.000, 20.000]
    - Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
```

.

```
rosrun tf view_frames
    pdf with information::
    view_frames Result
    Recorded at time: 1465466163.119
     base_link --> velodyne 
    Broadcaster: /robot_tf_publisher
    Average rate: 100.202 Hz
    Most recent transform: 1465466163.115 ( 0.005 sec old)
    Buffer length: 4.940 sec
```

.

```
rostopic echo /tf

    transforms: 
      - 
        header: 
          seq: 0
          stamp:        secs: 1465466125        nsecs: 274628467
          frame_id: base_link
        child_frame_id: velodyne
        transform: 
          translation:          x: 25133.0      y: 20.0         z: 20.0
          rotation:         x: 0.0      y: 0.0      z: 0.0      w: 1.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236435/velodyne-transform_node-error-require-extrapolation/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-06-08**:
It's probably normal to get those messages when starting up, but they should go away once the transform is available. Or, perhaps your tf broadcaster has a problem. Could you edit your question and post the relevant parts?

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2016-06-09**:
update done. Seems like tf is right, but I can not see the translation in rviz, maybe because the center is also translated. How can I check the transformation?

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2016-06-10**:
thank you very much, now I can see it is working with *transform_node _frame_id:=/base_link* and rviz with decay > 1. shall I close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the `rviz` TF display.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0